# Screw eyes that are screwed in counterclockwise?

Tags: screws

Is there such a thing as a screw eye that can be screwed in counterclockwise? 99% of screws are tightened clockwise. This one would be the opposite.

If this type of screw eye doesn't exist, is there another way to accomplish  the same thing?

Comment: If you can not find a reverse thread eye bolt then it will be near impossible to screw in a right hand thread bolt left handed ( turning it backwards ). If you accomplish this please let us know.   What are you trying to "accomplish" with a reverse thread eye bolt ??

Comment: A "screw eye" has a "lag" type thread, for wood (I have NEVER seen a left-hand thread version in 40 years, 20 of those selling builder's hardware). An "eye bolt" has machine threads (I have NEVER seen a left-hand thread version except those that come with turnbuckles). As @ Alaska man queried, what are you trying to accomplish and why do you need reverse thread?

Answer (score 3):

Screw eye turnbuckles have one screw eye reverse threaded. That's what makes it get longer/shorter when you turn the turnbuckle.

Comment: I looked for left handed eye lags and could only find machine threaded as Tim pointed out.+